# Spring Boot packaging the project to War

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, war

I have followed these steps to convert the pacakging from Jar to War.

But when i check my project folder or the build folder that is generated there is no war file generated only a war folder comes with MANIFEST.MF file

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging

The changes i did in my gradle build file

```
apply plugin: 'war'

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}


dependencies {      
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')      
}
```

Added a new ServletInitializer class

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the gradle command assemble in order to build the jar . This should help

```
gradle assemble
```